# Div filling all of the height in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a site which works on tablets, computers and phones in everything except Chrome. The main div should fill the screens height, whether it is full or not. It has a neutral grey background colour. In Chrome it only fills the size of the viewport, when scrolled or if the viewport size is changed the background colour doesn't adapt. I have tried everything I can think of and tested on Safari, Firefox and Edge without problems, what is up with Chrome?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='owstyles.css'/>

    <title>
      Layout experiment
    </title>

    </head>

  <body>
    <div id="holder">
            <div id="header">

            <div class="head-item">my logo here</div>
            <div class="head-item">other head item</div>

      </div><!--close header-->

      <div id="main">
              <h1>My Heading 1</h1>
                <h2>my heading 2</h2>

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et.</p>

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>

                <h2>heading 2</h2>

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>

        </div> <!--close main-->

          </div><!--close holder-->

            </body>

          </html>
```

And here is the CSS

```
*         {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          }

html      {
          height: 100%;
          }

body{
    background-color: #EAEDF0;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url('graphic/background.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    }

    h1  {
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        }

    h2  {
        margin-left: 1em;
        }


    p       {
        margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
        }

#holder  {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        color: #ffffff;
        height:100%;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: auto;
}

#header   {
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: flex;
          -webkit-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
        height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 2.5em;
        background-image: url(graphic/waves.jpg);
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        }


#main  {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      color: #000000;
      -webkit-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #EAEDF0;
      max-width: 960px;

}

#footer {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0em;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image:url('graphic/waves.jpg');
        }

.head-item {
          display: flex;
          margin: 2vw;
          height: 2vw;
          }
```

It is also live at [www.oceanwind.ch/test](http://www.oceanwind.ch/test)

Comment: I'm not sure what you need but  try deleting the styles of `html ` tag and add `min-heght: 100vh` to `body` tag.

Comment: This is because your html height is 100%
Try removing that it will work

Comment: It's better but the background colour of the "main" division only fills the content and not the rest of the screen, but now on the other browsers it will not fill the screen.

Comment: are you able to post a fiddle or code pen with this

Comment: following the link you provided I do not see the issue you are reporting and yes It was on chrome

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. On my main website with lots of other stuff, there is still an issue, I will have to track it down. If you would care to have a look it's at www.oceanwind.ch/new but there is quite a lot  of stuff to plough through. I don't know how to do a fiddle or a code pen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it

```
body {
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use flexbox in this case. Simply update the CSS as follows:

```
* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html {
    height: 100%;
  }

  body{
      background-color: #EAEDF0;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-image: url('graphic/background.jpg');
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
  }

  h1  {
      margin-left: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }

  h2  {
      margin-left: 1em;
  }


  p     {
      margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  }

  #holder  {
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-color: #EAEDF0;
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: auto;
  }

  #header   {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      flex-direction: row;
      height: auto;
      padding-bottom: 2.5em;
      background-image: url(graphic/waves.jpg);
      -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
  }


  #main  {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      color: #000000;
      -webkit-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #EAEDF0;
      max-width: 960px;

  }

  #footer {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      background-color: #00ff00;
      height:auto;
      -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
      justify-content: space-around;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 960px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0em;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-image:url('graphic/waves.jpg');
  }

 .head-item {
      display: flex;
      margin: 2vw;
      height: 2vw;
  }
```

You have used a lot of unnecessary CSS. Take time to tidy it up.

Comment: Thanks for that, yes there is too much code there. There is a lot more to my site than just this small piece. I will have to clean it up. I keep adding bits when a browser doesnt do what the others do. i will try with the main div not being a flex box. If I need it can I put a flexbox inide it? It will take me some time to put your suggestions into place,

Comment: Well, it all depends on how you arrange your div structure. Some options are better than others. And yes, did my solution worked for you? Do you still have issues now?

Comment: No. If you look at www.oceanwind.ch/test on chrome, If the initial window is small, and then it is enlarged, the background doesn't fill the space. I have a lot of issues with this over different browsers. I will have to go back to the start and try to begin again.

Comment: Yeah, I followed the link you gave. Everything looks fine. And yes, I am viewing from chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

As per your current CSS, You need to just remove height ***(Basically height can be effected to your code)***

You have 2(two) Option either remove option 1 or option 2

**Option: 1**

```
Body
{
height: 100%;
}

**Option: 2**

html 
{
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't get the required effect. The background of the main div will only cover the initial viewport. If I have to scroll the background colour doesnt come with it.